# Scheme: How do we write recursive procedure with lambda?

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, sicp

I was going through Structure and interpretation of computer programming by Brain harvey. I came across this question which i could not figure out how to do it.

How do we write recursive procedure with lambda in Scheme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: Use named `let` (if you are executing a recursive function immediately) or `rec` (if you are saving the recursive function for later execution).

---

The usual way is with `letrec`, or something that uses a `letrec` behind the scenes, like named `let` or `rec`. Here's a version of `(factorial 10)` using `letrec`:

```
(letrec ((factorial (lambda (x)
                      (if (< x 1) 1
                          (* (factorial (- x 1)) x)))))
  (factorial 10))
```

And the same thing using named `let`:

```
(let factorial ((x 10))
  (if (< x 1) 1
      (* (factorial (- x 1)) x)))
```

The key understanding here is that both versions are *exactly the same*. A named `let` is just a macro that expands to the `letrec` form. So because the named `let` version is shorter, that is usually the preferred way to write a recursive function.

---

Now, you might ask, what if you want to return the recursive function object directly, rather than execute it? There, too, you can use `letrec`:

```
(letrec ((factorial (lambda (x)
                      (if (< x 1) 1
                          (* (factorial (- x 1)) x)))))
  factorial)
```

There, too, is a shorthand for this, although not using named `let`, but instead using [`rec`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html):

```
(rec (factorial x)
  (if (< x 1) 1
      (* (factorial (- x 1)) x)))
```

The nice thing about using `rec` here is that you can assign the function object to a variable and execute it later.

```
(define my-fact (rec (factorial x)
                  (if (< x 1) 1
                      (* (factorial (- x 1)) x))))
(my-fact 10)  ; => 3628800
```

---

The more theoretical and "pure" way to create recursive functions is to use a [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). :-) But most practical Scheme programs do not use this approach, so I won't discuss it further.

Answer (score 5):

No need to write factorial body twice ;)

```
(((lambda (f)
   (lambda (x)
     (f f x)))
 (lambda (fact x)
   (if (= x 0) 1 (* x (fact fact (- x 1)))))) 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive function that calculates the factorial of 5 using lambda

```
((lambda (f x)
  (if (= x 0)
      1
      (* x (f f (- x 1)))))
 (lambda (f x)
  (if (= x 0)
      1
      (* x (f f (- x 1)))))
 5)
```

When you run this program in Drracket you get 120 :)